# Prevent Vim warning after autocommand changes file being edited

Tags: vim

I run a command every time a save a file which, among other things, lints the current file.  Vim does two annoying things which I wanted to avoid:

1. It asks me to press enter after the command was executed.
2. It notifies me that the current file has been modified outside of Vim.

How to get rid of this? I just want this to behave unobtrusively as ALE linters. This is my code:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.prisma :execute '!npx prisma format'
```

Comment: Here is how to lint your code without plugins: https://gist.github.com/romainl/ce55ce6fdc1659c5fbc0f4224fd6ad29

Answer (score 0):

[@romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl)'s comment gave me an idea on how to do it:

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.prisma silent write | silent :execute '!npx prisma format' | edit! %
```

It's not the cleanest way to do it but it works. `silent` hides the command output and `edit!` forces Vim to open the modified file.